# How to calculate Max(Date) and Min(Date) for DateType in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, date, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The dataframe has a date column in string type `'2017-01-01'`

It is converted to `DateType()`

```
df = df.withColumn('date', col('date_string').cast(DateType()))
```

I would like to calculate the `first day` and `last day` of the column. I tried with the following codes, but they do not work. Can anyone give any suggestions? Thanks!

```
df.select('date').min()
df.select('date').max()

df.select('date').last_day()
df.select('date').first_day()
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Aggregate with `min` and `max`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import min, max

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  "2017-01-01", "2018-02-08", "2019-01-03"], "string"
).selectExpr("CAST(value AS date) AS date")

min_date, max_date = df.select(min("date"), max("date")).first()
min_date, max_date
# (datetime.date(2017, 1, 1), datetime.date(2019, 1, 3))
```

Answer (score 12):

Additional way to do it in a line

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.agg(F.min("date"), F.max("date")).show()
```